# symfony2 querybuilder orderby count manytomany

Tags: symfony, sql-order-by, createquery

I have an entity called School, it has a ManyToMany relation "methods"

```
class School{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Method", inversedBy="schools")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="lk_access_method")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "asc"})
 */
protected $methods;
}
```

Now I want to write a createQueryBuilder that orders by de count "methods"

Something like:

```
$schools = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select("s")
            ->orderBy("COUNT(s.methods)")
            ->addOrderBy("s.name")
            ->setMaxResults($count)
            ->setFirstResult($pos)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But that didn't work... anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add join

```
->join('s.methods', 'm')
->orderBy("COUNT(m.id)")
```

**EDIT.**

```
->addSelect('COUNT(m.id) as nMethods')
->join('s.methods', 'm')
->groupBy('s.id')
->orderBy("nMethods", 'DESC')
```

Comment: isn't working... 
my error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 106: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
on the line where says COUNT(

Comment: Yes that works fine! Thanks! 
but now I got an 2 dimensional array of the school entity and the nMethods. 
I make a new array in a foreach loop with only the entity School in it, or is there a better way.

Comment: @LisaVanDaele you can use `AS HIDDEN` to get rid of the extra field in the results: `COUNT(m.id) AS HIDDEN nMethods`. This will work.

Comment: With the default join, if an item have no relations it won't be returned. to return also items with no relations (where count is 0) use leftjoin() instead of join()